# One computer has much lower internet speed than other devices

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, internet-connection, speed

A few days ago I had new internet connection installed – 100 Mb/s and my phone, my iPad and one laptop show on speedest.net around 90 Mb/s, which is great. Only one laptop shows around 15 Mb/s, sometimes up to 30 Mb/s. When I check speedtest on my phone in the same spot where the laptop stands it still shows around 90 Mb/s. This is a Dell Vostro 3400 i5-1135G7 with Fedora 36. The signal strength is full. The router is Telekom Speedport Pro Plus. I wouldn't want to have to plug the computer in through ethernet because the router is in another room.

Comment: What channels is it using, what wifi version, is it slow if you connect via a cable?

Comment: Is it slow if the computer is in the same room as the router?

Comment: 1.So I tried setting different channels, so that they don't clash with other wifis in the area and now it's 2-6 on 2.4GHz 802.11g / n / ax and 36,40,44,48,52,56,60,64 on 5 GHz 802.11n / ac / ax. I didn't notice any change in the Internet speed after that.
2. Yes it is still slow when the computer is in the same room as the router
3. It has full speed via the ethernet cable.